# Weird behaviour with Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I have a loop that is making multiple ajax gets.

```
for dataType in @dataTypes
            url = someUrl + dataType
            console.log(dataType)
            console.log url
            $.ajax(
                url : url
                type : 'GET'
                success : (data) => @populateSearchIndices(data,dataType)
            )
populateSearchIndices:(data,dataType)->
    console.log "looking at what indexes are there"
    console.log dataType
    indices = []
    for object in data
        indices = indices.concat(Object.keys(object))
    console.log "indices"
    console.log indices
    arr = @typeIndexMap[dataType]
    if arr 
        @typeIndexMap[dataType] = @typeIndexMap[dataType].concat(indices)
    else 
        @typeIndexMap[dataType] = indices
    console.log "typeIndexMap"
    console.log @typeIndexMap
```

The console.log in dataType always returns the last dataType in @dataTypes, despite the fact that the console.log dataType in the first function displays both, suggesting that a loop is occurring.

I printed out the url as well - they're both different, but the response I get is the exact same as if the last dataType were appended to someUrl and multiple gets were made with that url.

Why is this happening? I think this has something to do with the nature of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `success` callback:

```
success : (data) => @populateSearchIndices(data, dataType)
```

is just grabbing `dataType` as a reference that won't be evaluated until the callback is triggered. By the time that happens, `dataType` will be the last value in the `@dataTypes` array and all of your callbacks will use that same value.

You need to force `dataType` to be evaluated in the loop body and CoffeeScript has [`do`](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) for that:

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

So you want something more like this:

```
for dataType in @dataTypes
  do (dataType) ->
    url = someUrl + dataType
    #... as before
```

If you have a look at the corresponding JavaScript, you'll see that your loop body is converted to a function that is called with `dataType` as a parameter, the function wrapper and execution forces `dataType` to be evaluated (rather than just referenced) for each loop iteration.

Your `url` behaves as expected because you evaluated `dataType` when you build it:

```
url = someUrl + dataType
```

and then use it in the `$.ajax` call rather than dragging a reference around.